# confused about address of value in stack

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

below is some working - 16 bit x86 assembly

```
        global    _start

        section   .text
_start: mov ah, 0x0e

        mov bp, 0x8000
        mov sp, bp

        push "A"
        push "B"
        push "C"

        pop bx
        mov al, bl
        int 0x10

        pop bx
        mov al, bl
        int 0x10

        mov al, [0x7ffe]
        int 0x10
        
        jmp $
        
        times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
        dw 0 xaa55
```

I push 3 values onto the stack , and then print the first 2. I am attempting to print the third value by indirect adressing , hence mov al, [0x7ffe] - but question Is , because the stack has a base of 0x8000 and can only pop 16 bit values , wouldn't the address of the last character to be printed,- "a" be 0x8000 - 0x1 = 0x7FFF rather than 0x8000 - 0x2 , which is 0x7FFe as adressed in the code above , as 1 16-bit byte is 0x10?

Comment: The question is very hard to understand the way you've written it. When you `push "A"` you put 2 bytes on the stack: 0x41 at 0x7FFE and 0x00 at 0x7FFF. When you `mov al, [0x7ffe]`, the AL register gets the value 0x41, which is the ASCII code for `A`. What is the part where it's unclear?

Comment: @DarkAtom what part of the question is hard to understand?

Comment: a lot of it. For example, the "1 16-bit byte" part.

Comment: "1 16-bit byte" - I just meant a single byte comprised of 16 btis

Comment: which is exactly what is unclear. Unless you are talking about ancient machines from the 70s, a byte has 8 bits. Always.

Comment: okay thanks for clearing up a misconception of mine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In x86 real mode you cannot push an 8-bit value. Therefore your three `push` instructions are actually pushing the 16-bit values `0x0041`, `0x0042`, and `0x0043`. Since x86 is little-endian, the actual character part of the value comes "first", so the `0x41` representing "A" will be located at address `0x7ffe`.